# Filtering data by excluding certain codes from my dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
    employee_code      eligible_date**
         student   
         student   
         trainee   
         trainee            2020-05-29
         employee           2020-05-06  
         employee   
         employee           2020-07-01
```

What I want to do is to **exclude** students and trainees from my dataset.

```
    data = data[((data.employee_code == "student") | (data.employee_code == "trainee")) & (data.eligible_date.isnull())]
```

My code here does the opposite, it just includes them. Is there a simple way to change the code above to exclude them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data[~((data.employee_code...`

Comment: Does my edit help?

Comment: @G.Anderson Can you please add your comment as an answer? That was the simplest change to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `query`, it is easier to read:

```
filter = ['student', 'trainee']
data = data.query('employee_code not in @filter')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would boolean select student and trainee and invert the selection. Much faster and neater

```
m=df['employee_code'].isin(['student','trainee'])
df[~m].dropna()
```

Output

[image]

Alternatively

```
m=(df['employee_code'].isin(['student','trainee']))|(df.eligible_date.isnull())
m
df[~m]#.dropna()
```

Comment: eligible_date.isnull()

Comment: Edited. All you need is to dropna() or booalean select as follows m=(df['employee_code'].isin(['student','trainee']))|(df.eligible_date.isnull())

Answer (score 1):

```
data = data[~(data['employee_code'].str.contains('student|trainee')&
              data['eligible_date'].isnull())]
```

Comment: This does not have the eligible_date.isnull() condition